# Google App Engine python cannot upload certain static files

Tags: google-app-engine

I just noticed that some .jpg and .js are not uploading when I deploy the app from local machine to GAE.  I had no issue viewing these files prior, but I suddenly noticed this change yesterday.  Running GAE 1.9.3 w/ Python 2.7

As for .jpg files, it appears ones from photo are not uploading.

I have no clue why suddenly I cannot upload, hence display, certain key static files for my webapp.

As for observation:
1-Localhost has no issue displaying the image or run .js
2-yaml has not been altered at all in weeks
3-Deployment worked fine until last week.  I tried uploading our old code that previously worked without an issue now has the same issue.
4-I see many `Could not guess mimetype for ......` error during upload script
5-By default, I use Eclipse with PyDev+GAE+EGIT.  But I tried with GAELauncher with same results
6-Only photo-based images are not uploading; I see illustrations fine.  On the serving site, I get: `GET http://mysite.appspot.com/img/home-concept-item-1.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)` errors.  Again, just the few won't make it through (six to be exact), and two .js; others are fine...
7-From above, it is hard to believe I caused the issue, but something is needing change.

Here is my yaml (again, has not been altered for weeks and worked fine before):

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes    

handlers:
- url: /img/favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /vendor
  static_dir: vendor
- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:                                                                      
- name: jinja2                                                                  
  version: latest                                                               
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest           
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Please advise.  Your input will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide an awful lot more information.  How do you know they are not uploading, what evidence do you have ?  Are you sure you just can't download them ?   Your `app.yaml` is likely to be the cause, or caching if your expecting images to change.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks.  Your suggestion was taken and updated the posting.  I am seeing 404 Not Found errors, but happening to only photo-based images and two .js

Comment: "Could not guess mimetype"?  That message helps pinpoint.  From: [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) mime types: "If specified, all files served by this handler will be served using the specified MIME type. If not specified, the MIME type for a file will be derived from the file's filename extension."  So, check you extensions.  To force the mime_type, you can declare it in the static file handlers in app.yaml:

        - url: /js
          static_dir: js
          mime_type: "text/javascript"

Comment: @GAEfan thanks for the input.  I tried all that you have suggested with no luck..  I have three images next to each other, but one is still "missing" as I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ` error.  I am puzzled, especially our old code that worked fine now have same issue w/ deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a bug in Push-to-Deploy, where static files get lost, if you have any static file remapping in app.yaml.  Are you using the git repo and ptd?  If so, try deploying from the command line or GAELauncher.

Dump your caches, check skip_files in app.yaml

Comment: thanks.  Is there a way (command) to clear everything on server and try uploading fresh again?  If all clones as my localhost, I should see no issue.  Also, what's the best way to dump chaches (and where)?

Comment: Clear your browser cache through the browser preferences, or use Incognito mode in Chrome, or switch browser.  In the App Console, you can clear the memcache, in case you have some template caching in place.  Also, app engine urls are case-sensitive.  Check that.  Are there any log messages when deploying?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `skip_files:` option of your `app.yaml` file. Make sure you don't have some overly greedy expression like `(*.j*)` in there.

Comment: my yaml looks fine, I think.  And not all .jpg or .js are "lost." Only a few.

Answer (score 0):

Add upload to app.yaml since you need point *.js can be regex but you need check it.

See your code for example of syntax:

```
- url: /img/favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
```

See my code:

```
- url: /static/audio/(.*\.ogg)
  mime_type: application/ogg
  static_files: static/audio/\1
  upload: static/audio/(.*\.ogg)
```